# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MARIA DELGADO"

Tags: java

Ya intente convertir las lineas del archivo txt con long y aun asi me sale el error, que podria hacer? El archivo txt contiene nombres y numeros y pues con los numeros debo hacer unas conversiones.
El txt contiene esto:

```
JUAN PEREZ
2040
160
25
36
MARIA DELGADO
9985
160
32
0
JORGE MARIN
1155
165
55
20
```

Código:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Dowhile
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            double salario;
            File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Acer\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\nomina.txt");
            FileReader archivo_lec = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader mediciones = new BufferedReader(archivo_lec);
            
            String linea;
            linea = mediciones.readLine();
            
            while(linea !=null){
                System.out.println(linea);
                linea=mediciones.readLine();
                int horas;
                horas = Integer.parseInt(linea);
             
            }
            Ya intente convertir las lineas del archivo txt con long y aun asi me sale el error, 
            que podria hacer? El archivo txt contiene nombres y numeros y pues con los numeros 
            debo hacer unas conversiones. 
            
            mediciones.close();
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException error) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien tu problema, pero entiendo que te causa errores al formatear una cadena como un Integer. Lo que deberías hacer es validar si la información leida es un entero. A continuación pongo el código que valida la línea cuando se ingresa cualquier entero con una expresión regular, además, tienes que leer la siguiente línea al final del ciclo while, ya que al colocarlo al inicio, y lee la siguiente línea cuando estás en la última línea obtienes un NullPointerException.

```
import java.io.*;


class Dowhile
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            double salario;
            File archivo = new File("file.txt");
            FileReader archivo_lec = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader mediciones = new BufferedReader(archivo_lec);
            
            String linea;
            linea = mediciones.readLine();
            
            while(linea != null){
                //System.out.println(linea);

                if (linea.matches("[0-9]*")){
                    int horas;
                    horas = Integer.parseInt(linea);
                    System.out.println("horas: " + horas    );
                }
                linea=mediciones.readLine(); // Se cambió la posición de esta línea
            }
            mediciones.close();
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException error) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda bro, voy a ver que tal

Comment: de nada, y mucha suerte.